# Copy from array to array by refenrence in function

Tags: c++, string, function, reference, char

I have no idea why it doesn't work. What is more I can't even say what are errors about ;/
Can any1 explain what are errors about?

The code is suposed to :
create a string with word like - mom.
then create 2d array to fill it by string. Free spaces fill with _.So mom box =

> [m] [o]
>
> [m] [_]

now fill next array with text that follows from colums. mom_ filled to new array will look like mmo_. Then I cout crypted text. I hope u understood whatI did there :D

here is code

```
//wal = kolumny=wiersze
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
void pole(int &a,const int &l);
void tab(const char &s[],char &d[], char &f[],const int a);
int main(){
    string code;
    cin >> code;
    int wall=1;
    int d=code.length();
    char tekst[d];   
    pole(wall,d);
    strcpy(tekst,code);
    char kw[wall][wall];
    char szyfr[d];
    tab(tekst,kw,szyfr,wall);   
    for (int i=0;i<d;i++) 
    cout << szyfr[i] << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
void pole(int &a,const int &l){
    if (a*a < l)
    pole(a+=1,l);
}
void tab(const char &s[],char &d[], char &f[],const int a){
    int i=0;
    for (int x=0;x<a;x++,i++){
        for (int y=0;y<a;y++,i++){
            if(s[i])
            d[x][y]=s[i];
            else d[x][y]=='_';
            f[i]=d[x][y];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're mixing C++ with C. C++ doesn't have [VLAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d[x][y]` has no meaning in `tab` d is a single dimension array. You will have to pass the first dimension as argument and use it when indexing. Something like:

```
void tab(const char &s[],char* &d, char &f[],const int a, int d_num_cols){
    int i=0;
    for (int x=0;x<a;x++,i++){
        for (int y=0;y<a;y++,i++){
            if(s[i])
            d[x*d_num_cols + y]=s[i];
            else d[x*d_num_cols + y]=='_';
            f[i]=d[x*d_num_cols + y];
        }
    }
}
```